# How do I allow querystrings in a codeigniter application?

Tags: url, codeigniter, query-string

I'd like to have my codeigniter site to accept URLs like the following:-
www.domain.com/?gclid=CM5D19f6OlKoC7RRc8QodUn6Pxw

Can anyone suggest how if a user came to my site via this or similar URL they would be redirected to the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public function index() {
   $gclid = $this->input->get('gclid');
   ($gclid) ? header("Location: /") : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - the problem I currently have any URL like domain.com/?gclid=k4kl543pds goes to the error 404.

Is there a way to prevent it going to an error 404 in codeigniter when a querystring like the one above is used?

Comment: `public function index() {
   $gclid = $this->input->get('gclid');
   $array = array('CM5D19f6OlKoC7RRc8QodUn6Pxw', 'xxx'); // allow gclids
   (in_array($array, $gclid)) ? header("Location: /") : null;
}`